# Powerbeats Pro Bluetooth's doesn't work on Fedora

Tags: fedora, audio, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to my PowerBeats Pro through the Bluetooth panel and the command line panel but it doesn't pair my computer to my PowerBeats. Why doesn't it work and how can i fix it or find ways to fix it ?

Error message:

```
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried and is there any more information you can provide than "it doesn't work"?  i.e. Error messages, doesn't find the device at all, find the device and says connected but then doesn't play audio, etc.

Comment: @Jesse_b there aren't any error messages, just it cannot pair with it. Even in command line, it just says that it cannot connect to it.

Comment: Saying that it cannot connect would be an error message.

Comment: @Jesse_b It only says "Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed"

Comment: After what command does it give that **error message**?

Comment: @Jesse_b `connect {BluetoothDeviceUUID}`

Comment: I was having trouble connecting my phone and this helped me
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/bluetooth-doesnt-display-pin-code-for-pairing/8496

Comment: There is the error : ```No such schema “org.blueman.general”``` @Matthew